# Document pattern matching

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, ocr, document

We have like a thousand documents (images) and we need to find any pattern repeated in all of them.

Anybody knows if there is any recognition tool which do this job and return the pattern?

For example any string available in all or most of the documents

Regards!

Comment: Design patterns are completely unrelated OCR and  text search . Just look for any OCR product to convert your images to text then use a search engine to find what you want

Comment: I agree with the above.  If your search is for text-based objects (string, regular expressions, etc) then handle the OCR as first step and get your data set, then use some search or data capture as the next step.  Also, I think you'll have to specify what you are looking for and technology can return if that is found.  Not the opposite.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.
There is any free tool or online app which can ocr a lot of pages of a pdf file at once?
Im not able to find any without this restriction